# PNP water level detector circuit

Tags: transistors, switches, pnp

I'm trying to build a simple water level detector using BC557 PNP transistor (there's already a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346148/water-level-indicator-with-pnp-transistor) but doesn't solve my problem...)

Circuit 1 below is what I'm thinking to build based on the standard biasing of PNP circuits (Circuit 2) as there's only 1 power source available. However, without a power source to reverse bias Emitter, I'm not able to have a Collector current. I think I'm doing something wrong here as it should work based on [this](http://www.rason.org/Projects/transwit/transwit.htm) for example. I can simulate an emitter current in Circuit 1 but no matter what resistors I use on the Emitter end (using 20k and 200k here) I cannot get a Collector current. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? This is my [simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAXcGm8MFcMQGsBVFiCYwEeSBjDEahPHkIpiCYvUnQNKmljQksxSMRC4qAEwYAzAIYBXADYc2AJ0HCUeTyBQpeKjRINgA3PwxhHgiBbFEoWip%20BKopNgB3GPNhIWyoDN8432JCfMzMAQqssGiQsFVff155Ssi-EGt7Zw4mJwZLcBSoWHZMwl4qybaQj0Vm5IRokQTguAK5vI1Y0TZ6gS2-AIpcyY7bRxde-sHU4chRkEI2qqeowIKDooOSsse2r9yRRC4Ve3F4oKBCRoSXiqR07mOXh8ByaKzWXEW832uWWYgg2gQYDwYAQhFM6hoYAwCDUEhgJHGQhQCCwkEoGB%20FjOXRcHxObVBVWBtHGfAEG0hVGh1FuaQ8otRotxfngITGWLBYt%20LTyoqBCL1AiVySCqpCAGdHhMjgrSUN7E5zQwCrbSgrpmwAB7ccjYVh%20bBIP28Ca8ADCAEs3ABjBwRjgAHXN7G9CGk5n941KwdofnDUdj8aTKDYQA).

[image: 4]

Comment: Try this https://tinyurl.com/y8gbft5w

Comment: you can do this 3V too and adjust R values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: Learning curve error with Falstad drawing.

You had Red Dot below LED indicating it was not a junction (disconnected) So shink line and add another wire as in my comment link fixed.

But you had 12V with a pretty big LED current which only uses a couple volts which is very inefficient. So I [assumed 20mA here.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMZICYaoOyYMxgByoBsAnCZiHBAgCw6UCmAtIogFAAuSNNSiqSEgNYCILPpHLYiOOJkT4SRfIhBMUsDDURxdWMDhn4ay%20nggATBgDMAhgFcANhzYAnQcNT4PIVKl4QNJhgbABuvpjCPBECOKLgIDQQ-AkQKHBsAO4xIHE%20eThZ%20cJCIErgRVgCVTmI0SGIRCXV-j41AlZ2ThxMjgwWSKlQYOzZRLw1iKU1Ie4mvCKU0YsQ6LBF87kCcKV5DU2U06071ZG%20IJ0Ozr39g2nDoyBEZzXPUQFFJ1uHAuUhY2c8l89mEnmc6rw3t97kkkPE0pAMu4vvxvF8-AFfDBOEsFikUSkxKp1IiFDoiGAyHBtMF8AgSaRxkJUHJglRMPgKOYLjYri5suizlCZqDNotNnsErCEPd0m4nhNWuM%20PE1tixnj3iqKtkprEBMqQe5DQbNQk1diAM4K3xKiZwIgJVR2RyWhhFZUsx2es4hAAe3C5rF8QVydUSIZAAGEAJauADG9hjHAAOpb2AHdN4cMGiHBs%20GJrxYwmk6nLahKi9wdNfWwgA)

Also remember to reduce hFE to 10% of maximum when using a switch.